# Setting value to default otherwise counting if it is NULL with QGIS expression

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, qgis-expression

I am looking to expand on this expression, I currently have the ability to count up following putting a tree no in, so I put in 'T001' then the formula counts on.

However I want to put 'T001' as default, then each new record counts from this, I currently have the following:

```
if("Tree No:" IS NULL,
    'T' || lpad(to_string(maximum(to_int(right("Tree No:", 3))) + 1), 3, '0'),
    "Tree No:"
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression that would help you here is [`coalesce()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#coalesce) which returns the first non-`NULL` value in a series of expressions entered as arguments to the function (refer to the link for examples).

In this case, you want your `maximum()` to find the highest `Tree No:` value (without the T), but when there are no features in the layer at all, of course `maximum()` returns `NULL` - then you want it to fall back to starting from `1`.

Here is how that would work with your expression:

```
if("Tree No:" IS NULL,
    'T' || lpad(to_string(coalesce(maximum(to_int(right("Tree No:", 3))) + 1, 1)), 3, '0'),
    "Tree No:"
    )
```